# C : Implement sizeof_32() and sizeof_64() for 32 - bit and 64 - bit compilations

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging, gcc

I am building a custom debugger compiled as 64 - bit (`cc -q64 ...`) which can attach to both 32 - bit and 64 - bit executables and peep into memory segments. I am facing the following scenario:

`a.h`:

```
struct dll{
    void *nxt;
    void *prev;
};

struct obj{
    struct dll link;
    int unique_id;    //Unique id to find this structure in the stack or data area
    ...    //Some more members
};
```

`a.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"a.h"

struct obj ob1;

main(){
    struct obj ob 2;
    ob1.id = 0x189acf;
    ob2.id = 0x98bdac;
    while(1);
}
```

`debug.c`:

```
#include"a.h"

main(){
    //attaching toprocess a.c
    //peeping into stack area to find 0x98bdac found at address1
    //Peeping into data area to find 0x189acf found at address2
    //Using address1 - sizeof(struct dll) trying to reach the begining of obj1
    //Using address2 - sizeof(struct dll) trying to reach the begining of obj2
}
```

The problem encountering is:
    When a.c is compiled in 32 - bit mode the size of `struct dll` is 4+4= 8 bytes but in the debuger (always a 64 - bit) finds size of `struct dll` 8+8 = 16 bytes thus in the debugger doing `adress1 - sizeof(struct dll)`  takes me off course by 8 bytes from begining of ob1 & similar for ob2.
    I have lot of such structures declared in `a.h` which have several members of data a well as pointers and sub-structures which makes it infeasible to calculate structure sizes by individually finding out sizes of each member and summing it to find total struct size.

I am looking for an implementation of a method sizeof_32() and sizeof_64() which would calculate size of the structures as per 32 - bit and 64 - bit.

Thanks...

Comment: Why are you using a 64 bit debugger to debug a 32-bit executable, or vice versa?

Comment: I am building a generic debugger which supports both 32 - bit & 64 - bit at the same time and 64 - bit programs are working fine only 32 - bit once are causing trouble.

Comment: Yeah, okay.   Problem is that `sizeof` for most types (`int`, structs, etc) is actually independent of whether the executable is 32-bit or 64-bit.   You either need to build your debugger with assumed (or hard-coded) knowledge about how each compiler works, or somehow coerce each compiler to put information about `sizeof` for various types into the executable (e.g. as part of debugging information that the compiler outputs for use by the debugger).  The former potentially breaks if a compiler is updated.  The latter - even if possible - means you need to read your compiler documentation.

Comment: Very True... The problem is mainly with pointer types that is architecture dependent. Hard coding will not make my debugger robust and the later option though possible still is difficult especially in case of large structure which has numerous members each of which further may be a structure itself and also holds pointers in different locations, parsing through them all is hectic. That is the reason I am looking for a flexible sizeof operator which returns result according to user requirement.

Comment: You need more than `sizeof` for each target architecture; you also need `offsetof`. Summing the sizes of each member of a struct won't get you the correct offset, because there's also padding issues. The compiler will place all this info in the executable if you give gcc the `-g` option. [libdwarf](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libdwarf/) will help you read that info.